# How do I get the Onmouseover method to apply universally to all links?

Tags: class, styling, highlighting, onmouseover

We're aware of that amazing trick which allows users to highlight a link.  But, you must repeat it for each link.  for example:  a href="https://www.yahoo.com" Onclick="window.open(this.href); return false"  onmouseout="this.style.color = '#0000ff';" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#e3FF85';" align="justify">Yahoo.   But, I would like this code to apply to every link on the page.   I've explored 2 possible methods.  One is to use STYLE TYPE  and CLASS= methods.  Another possibility is using STYLE H1 /H1  (similar to W3 schools).  But, I haven't even come close to getting a universal application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You can try this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i)
{
    links[i].onmouseenter = function() {links[i].style.color = '#e3FF85';};
    links[i].onmouseout= function() {links[i]..style.color = '#0000ff';};
}
```

You get the list of all links using `getElementsByTagName('a')` (`'a'` is tag name for links), and you can do anything you want with them.

**2.** You can also try it with jquery:

```
var allLinks = $('a');
allLinks.mouseenter(function() { $(this).css('color', '#e3FF85'); });
allLinks.mouseout(function() { $(this).css('color', '#0000ff'); })
```

**3.** If you just care about changing style (like color or background) when mouse is over your link, you can do it from CSS:

```
a:hover
{
    color: #123456;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The #3 comment worked absolutely perfectly.   And, that simple code worked for everything too.   One little code applied to all.    Aside from that, I'm curious regarding answer #1.  I wasn't sure where the onmouseout="this.style.color = '#0000ff';"  would go.   and where the benefit was, compared to answer #3.   I'll look into that further, just for my own curiosity.

Comment: @MediaReform When you have `var links` (array of all links in your file), you can do much more with them than simply change their color on hover. You can for example add `onclick` event handlers, or animate hovering with some jquery (e.g. `links[i].onmouseover = function() { $(links[i]).animate(/* your animation here */); };`).